# How to Handle onClick is Null on Shared React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a shared React component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  ...
`;

export default function InvisibleActionButton(props) {
  return (
    <StyledButton onClick={() => props.clickHandler()}>{props.buttonLabel}</StyledButton>
  )
};
```

I want to be able to use this button in instances where there is a clickHandler and in instances without. For example:

```
const registerClick = () => {
  props.history.push("/register");
};

return (
  <InvisibleActionButton clickHandler={registerClick} buttonLabel={"No account? Register here!"} />
)
```

and:

```
return (
  <StyledForm onSubmit={registerClick}>
    <InvisibleActionButton type="submit" buttonLabel={"Register"} />
  </StyledWrapperDiv>
)
```

The first instance works fine but in the second instance I get `props.clickHandler is not a function` since I'm not sending any clickHander prop. How can I generalize my shared component to use the clickHander when one is provided, and ignore it when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way you could do is this(you dont have to manually set everywhere its shared component should handle this logic):

```
    const {clickHandler} = props;
    <StyledButton onClick={clickHandler?clickHandler:null}>{props.buttonLabel}</StyledButton>
```

Here is codesandox of this poc:https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sun-62xx3?file=/src/App.js:0-311

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let test = () => console.log("hello");
  test = null;
  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={test ? test : null}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do one of these

```
// spread and assign default value as null
export default function InvisibleActionButton({clickHandler = null, ...props}) {
  return (
    <StyledButton onClick={clickHandler}>{props.buttonLabel}</StyledButton>
  )
};
```

or

```
// check if handler is function(this is needed to avoid any other truthy values) else assign null
export default function InvisibleActionButton(props) {
  return (
    <StyledButton onClick={typeof props.clickHandler === 'function' ? () => props.clickHandler() : null }>{props.buttonLabel}</StyledButton>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the shared component; the `onClick` function can be set to null, as so:

```
return (
  <StyledForm onSubmit={registerClick}>
    <InvisibleActionButton type="submit" clickHandler={() => null} buttonLabel={"Register"} />
  </StyledWrapperDiv>
)
```